# How to create access package

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I am new to azure AD. I have been asked to create a access package but i am not sure how to How to create access packages using bicep code? any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

An access package enables you to do a one-time setup of resources and policies that automatically administers access for the life of the access package. This article describes how to create a new access package. You can create access package following this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-create

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i was looking to create access packages using azure bicep code.